# Remove event listener (keydown)

Tags: javascript, events, listener

How to remove `eventlistener` in code below. This is an example but exactly the same I want to do in my project and it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
const removeClick = document.querySelector('.remove-click');
let border = 1;

borderBtn.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => changeBorder(e));

function changeBorder(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 17) {
      borderBtn.style.border = `${++border}px solid black`;
      if (border === 6) {
         removeEvent();
      }
   }
}

function removeEvent() {
   borderBtn.removeEventListener('keydown', changeBorder)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an anonymous function `(e) => changeBorder(e)` as eventListener so it will be hard for you to remove it.
Converting `changeBorder` to an arrow function will do the trick.

```
const removeClick = document.querySelector('.remove-click');
let border = 1;

borderBtn.addEventListener('keydown', changeBorder);

const changeBorder = (e) => {
   if (e.keyCode === 17) {
      borderBtn.style.border = `${++border}px solid black`;
      if (border === 6) {
         removeEvent();
         console.log('border 6px');
      }
   }
}

function removeEvent() {
   borderBtn.removeEventListener('keydown', changeBorder)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, you're a star!! Could be easy but I'm a beginner in JS

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the calling of removeEvent  inside changeBorder function to bottom maybe the border is never equal to 6:

````
const removeClick = document.querySelector('.remove-click');
let border = 1;

borderBtn.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => changeBorder(e));

function changeBorder(e) {
   if (e.keyCode === 17) {
      borderBtn.style.border = `${++border}px solid black`;
      if (border === 6) {
        
         console.log('border 6px');
      }
   }
 removeEvent();
}

function removeEvent() {
   borderBtn.removeEventListener('keydown', changeBorder)
}```
````

Or you can call it in the begining of changeBorder function to make sure.

To be sure that the removeEvent is called you can do :

```
function removeEvent() {
       console.log("remove event called");
       borderBtn.removeEventListener('keydown', changeBorder)
    }
```